# What is difference between Proxy and Persistent in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

In hibernate, an object is persistent if it is associated with a session. We can make object persistent by using methods like save(), persist() but then what is Proxy I can't undersatand ??

Comment: Read: _Java Persistence with Hibernate_.

Comment: Thank you, I read that topic.

Comment: Thank you, I read that topic just. 13.1.3 Understanding proxies
Proxies are placeholders that are generated at runtime. Whenever Hibernate returns an instance of an entity class, it checks whether it can return a proxy instead and avoid a database hit.

Comment: Right. But your question is still ill-posed. Hibernate uses so-called proxies when it can because, among other things, it can _intercept_ method calls. That is, when a getter is called, eg. `entity.getSomeOneToOneAssociatedEntity()`, the proxy can first fetch it from the database to _lazily_ initialize the member field and return the object. This allows Hibernate to initialize corresponding member fields to `null`, thus avoiding to hit the database if you just need a `reference' to a persisted entity. There's a lot to learn about proxies and their uses. I recommend that you invest some time.